# pass value from html to javascript as array

Tags: javascript, asp.net, arrays, vb.net

I write a code that gives value from database and saves them in a list and I put list into array and send it to ASP hiddenField.
I want to pass this data to JavaScript var as array. How can I do it?
I want to save values as string in array.

aspx:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnCity_BillMonth" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnCount_BillMount" runat="server" />
```

aspx.vb:

```
 hdnCity_BillMonth.Value = String.Join(",", City)
 hdnCount_BillMount.Value = String.Join(",", Value)
```

City and Value are List

```
 var City_BillMounth ;
 var Count_BillMounth;
```

Comment: are you using .net mvc frame work?

Comment: u got the list values in coma separated form ?then just assign the hidden field value to a variable in js. like var hdnvalue=document.getElementById("hiddenfieldid"); then split the string using comma like var samar=hdnvalue.split(',')

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV my hiddenfield value in html is like this: value="a,b,c"

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV i use asp.net classic

Comment: did you got the output ? let me know if you still have any problems ?

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV I see value in html but I have problem to pass javascript. See below answer please, I write some desc

Comment: what is ContentPlaceHolder1_hdnCount_BillMount ???

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV ID of hiddenfield tag. It generate by asp

Comment: what happend when directly used hdnCity_BillMonth ??

Comment: refer this link i have include an example there http://jsfiddle.net/wj6ohxtx/

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV same error

Comment: did you check with the example what i had provided ? if u get null then first  your server side code may be the value does not set to hidden field. or hidden field name may be wrong.

Comment: may be your are trying to call the value of the hidden field before it may assign.can i see your html and corresponding javascript.only call the js function after setting your hidden field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're joining city values with a "," symbol you can easily convert it into a java script array using **split** like this:

> I assume you are getting your **hdnCity_BillMonth** values like "city1, city2,city3,...cityN"

```
 var City_BillMounth = [];
 City_BillMounth = hdnCity_BillMonth.split(",");
 console.log("city Array: "+ City_BillMounth );
```

do the same for the `hdnCount_BillMount` as well.

Comment: thanks. But I debug It and throw this error:
TypeError
message:"document.getElementById(...) is null"
I use:
var Count_BillMounth = []
        Count_BillMounth = document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_hdnCount_BillMount').split(",");

Comment: I see this in html:
<input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hdnCity_BillMonth" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_hdnCity_BillMonth" value="city1,city2,city3,city4,city5" />

Comment: same error :( But I solve that by your idea.. tnx very much :)